# Export multiple "files" from a single compilation

Tags: javascript, webpack

I can easily transpile my code into a single module via the following strategy with webpack:

```
{
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'totem-ui',
  }
}
```

Where my `src/index.js` file looks as follows:

```
export { default as Button } from 'src/atoms/Button';
```

This can be consumed by third party applications like so:

```
import { Button } from 'totem-ui';
```

However, what I am trying to accomplish is something similar to how `react-router` or `lodash` does it. For example, with react-router, you can import a single module like this:

```
import Router from 'react-router/lib/Router';
```

In my case, it would look like this:

```
import Button from 'totem-ui/atoms/Button';
```

How is this accomplished via webpack? What is this pattern called?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the library and libraryTarget option -

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget

Also checkout this boilerplate which i think tackles the same issue -

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library